# script editor "RUN" "debug" "functions" buttons disabled

Tags: google-apps-script

1. 

- Im trying to write a simple script for portfolio tracking on google sheets. Click " tools" " Script editor"
  After finishing the script I noticed the buttons mentioned in the title we're light gray.
- I hope to enable the " Run" button so I can use my script
- Also received an error about the scirpt not being good, when trying to save the script. So unfortunately I lost my efforts

Comment: Are you the owner of the sheet? What error are you receiving? Can you share the code as well?

Comment: If the script is not well-formed, you cannot save it. If you don't know where exactly is the problem, select everything and comment it out, so then at least you'll be able to save the file.